# How to keep URL unchanged after redirecting from one subdomain to another subdomain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect all the queries from `mobile.mydomain.net` to `web.mydomain.net`, keeping the URL `mobile.mydomain.net` displayed in the address bar.

The directory structure in my service provider is the following:

```
/root  
-/vrmd  
--/homepages  
---/myusername  
----/mydomain  
-----/subdomains  
------/web  
-------/public  
------/mobile
```

In my service provider configuration the address `www.mydomain.net` points to `/mydomain/`, the address `web.mydomain.net` points to `/mydomain/subdomains/web/public/` and the address `mobile.mydomain.net` points to `/mydomain/subdomains/mobile/`.

If I echo the value of the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` constant in a simple PHP script (`/mobile/index.php`), it outputs `/homepages/myusername/mydomain/subdomains/mobile`.

I have some questions:

1) Where should I put the rewrite conditions and rules? In an `.htaccess` file under `/mydomain` or better under `/mydomain/subdomains/mobile`...?

2) Which conditions and rules should I write? For example, I want `mobile.mydomain.net/blog` to show only the contents of `web.mydomain.net/blogs`, but not the address.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can't silently redirect domains like that with the Apache rewrite engine - which is probably a good thing, since this could end up as a pretty nasty security breach if someone was able to upload a malicious .htaccess to your site somehow.

You would be better off implementing a front-facing controller in your mobile site that then included the content and libraries from your main website.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'll try to do that!